# What is the probability Amy wins a lottery prize for correctly choosing 5, not six, numbers...

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here is the full question: What is the probability that Amy wins a lottery prize for correctly choosing 5, not six, numbers out of six integers chosen at random from the integers between 1 and 40 inclusive?

So, what I've gotten so far is that the total number is C(40, 6): Out of 40, choose 6 cards. Next, I've gotten that, out of the 6 cards chosen out of 40, choose 5: C(6,5). So, should the probability be $\frac{C(6,5)}{C(40,6)}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you have to choose $1$ number out of $34(=40-6)$ numbers not correctly. Therefore the probability to choose $5$ out of $6$ numbers correctly is

$$\large{\frac{{6\choose 5} {34 \choose 1} }{40 \choose 6}}$$